# limited access to pcs that are connected at a computer's network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet-connection, wired-networking, ics

I have two computers, both windows 8. And I also have only one socket for wired Internet. So I connected the one with the socket, and I created a wireless network, so for the other to be able to use Internet as well. The network was created successfully, and I am able to connect to that from my second computer.

However, the connection at the second computer is shown that is limited, and I cannot connect with Internet, although I managed to authenticate with the network.

Do you know why is that and how I am able to fix it?

Comment: You have two statement that contradict each other.  You said you were able to connect to the network on th esecond computer.  What did you use to create this virtual access point

Comment: How exactly did you set things up?  Did you setup and start the HostedNetwork? Did you enable Internet Connection Sharing on the wired network adapter?  Related info: http://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-share-wi-fi-in-windows-8-with-internet-connection-sharing-ics/

Answer (score 0):

there's how to setup a computer to be a bridge to internet connection
http://www.wikihow.com/Bridge-an-Internet-Connection
make sure you did all the steps right